# Php Nusoap fails with latin characters

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I am developing a webservice using Nusoap to send xml data, and this time I have to send data with latin characters like 'ó'. However when I put it in the soap client it stops working. Below is a summary of code being develped to test sending xml with latin characters.

This is ths summary of server code being developed:

```
include_once("nusoap/nusoap.php");
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("PersonImport","urn:PersonImport");

$server->register("PersonImport",array("login" => "xsd:string", 'senha' => 'xsd:string', 'fornecedor' => 'xsd:string'),array("return" => "xsd:string"),"urn:PersonImport","urn:PersonImport#PersonImport");


function PersonImport($login,$senha,$fornecedor) {

    //Just for debug purposes
    $return = "My login Is <b>".$login . "</b> And My senha Is <b>".$senha."</b> And My fornecedor Is <b>".$fornecedor."</b>.";

    (...)(ommited code, xml parsing and response xml generation)

    return $return;
}
```

This is ths summary of client code:

```
<?php

require_once("nusoap/nusoap.php");
$client = new soapclient("example.com?wsdl");


$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>";
$xml .= "<fornecedor>";
$xml .= "<NAME1>Gian</NAME1>";
$xml .= "<MCOD1>Giancarlo SA</MCOD1>";
$xml .= "<STCD1>80048303000113</STCD1>";
$xml .= "<STCD2>55670185501</STCD2>";
$xml .= "<STCD3>5508150087</STCD3>";
$xml .= "<RG>359730553</RG>";
$xml .= "<STRAS>rua itororó</STRAS>";
$xml .= "<HOUSE_NUM1>81</HOUSE_NUM1>";
$xml .= "<HOUSE_NUM2>301</HOUSE_NUM2>";
$xml .= "<ORT02>Menino Deus</ORT02>";
$xml .= "<PSTLZ>90110290</PSTLZ>";
$xml .= "<REGIO>RS</REGIO>";
$xml .= "<ORT01>Porto Alegre</ORT01>";
$xml .= "<TELF1>32335675</TELF1>";
$xml .= "<TELFX>32335675</TELFX>";
$xml .= "<SMTP_ADDR>teste@teste.com</SMTP_ADDR>";
$xml .= "<ERDAT>2016-10-04</ERDAT>";
$xml .= "<ChangeData>2016-10-04</ChangeData>";
$xml .= "<StartData>2016-10-04</StartData>";
$xml .= "<OffData>2016-10-04</OffData>";
$xml .= "</fornecedor>";

$result = $client->PersonImport("login","password", $xml);


echo $result;
```

The line

```
$xml .= "<STRAS>rua itororó</STRAS>";
```

has a special character. If I remove the 'ó' character it works.

I tried to set encoding on xml:

```
$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>";
```

This worked for me when I had to parse xml with SimpleXML Parser, but it didn't work on soap.

I tried to set header of the page for utf8 or ISO-8859-1 like this:

```
header("Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

or:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

I tried to use htmlentities, but the entity for 'ó' is '& o a c u t e;' which has the special character '&' and then the same problem happens.

function serialize didn't resolve the problem.

I couldn't find an answer until now on google.

Is it possible to pass latin special characters using nusoap? There must be a way.

Comment: Looks like I found a way. Using CDATA I can escape the '&', so I can use htmlentities on strings, like this: `$xml .= "<STRAS><![CDATA[".htmlentities("Rua Itororó")."]]></STRAS>";`. I'm testing it, if it works always ok I will use it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found a way. Using CDATA I can escape the '&', so I can use htmlentities on strings, like this:

```
$xml .= "<STRAS><![CDATA[".htmlentities("Rua Itororó")."]]></STRAS>";
```